# PHP how to disable queries after one week later

Tags: php, mysql

I worked on ads project, any posts on it have certain period to display,
**example:** ( toyota cara model 2011 for sell ) this add will expire after one week.
when i inserted it into database i select that it will disabled  after one week all i need right now that after one week this post disabled automatically from query in front page

How can I do it using PHP and MYSQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of running cron jobs or whatever: Only SELECT ad listings that have been posted in the last week.

```
SELECT `listing_title`, `etc` FROM `ad_listing`
WHERE `date_posted` BETWEEN date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND now();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest and cleanest way is to create a `cronjob` with the script needed to remove/disable your data and then set it to run on that day.

Here is a small example on how to do it: http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

This way you wont have unnecessary information in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use time limitation in your query, for example

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE model="toyta" and submitted_time > '2012-11-8 20:31:23'
```

i hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Create a field that stores the time a week in advance, either through PHP or a database trigger, then on your searches , add- WHERE `field` > now()

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the MySQL event scheduler, if your version is 5.1 or higher, and you have SUPER privileges. It's like a cron job but performed by MySQL.

More details available at
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html